# Which datatype should I use to store switch port numbers

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I want to store the values for Switch Ports inside my SQL Server 2008 database. But which datatype will be best to use ?

Comment: What kind of values are those? Fixed numbers -> use `INT`. Fractional numbers -> use `DECIMAL(p, s)`. Something else -> most likely use `VARCHAR(n)`

Comment: i think port can have values from 0 to 65535. and can not contain fraction . so I can use int. but if I want the port number to only allow values from 0 to 65535, then how I can specify the maximum number of digits Int can store and the number range?

Comment: possible duplicate of [unsigned short data type in my Sql server 2008 r2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17348848/unsigned-short-data-type-in-my-sql-server-2008-r2)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your ports have possible values of 0 through 65535, you could use something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.YourTable
 ( Port INT NOT NULL
      CONSTRAINT CHK_Port CHECK(Port >=0 AND Port <= 65535)
 )
```

With this `CHECK CONSTRAINT`, you make sure you only get valid entries; if you try to insert a negative value, or something beyond 65535 - then you'll get an error and the `INSERT` doesn't happen