# unsigned short data type in my Sql server 2008 r2

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I want to store Port numbers in my SQL server database. In general and any port can have values from (0 to 65,535).

And on the following link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s3f49ktz%28v=vs.71%29.aspx it is mentioned that “unsigned short”  will be suitable for storing Port number.

But in my case I am suing Sql server 2008 r2, so which data type I can use to represent “unsigned short”?

Regards

Answer (score 2):

See the [documentation on data types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187752%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

You *could* use a [decimal/numeric](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187746%28v=sql.105%29.aspx):

```
Precision     Storage bytes
1-9           5
10-19         9
20-28         13
29-38         17
```

but even the smallest precision (1-9) is 5 bytes.

Looking at the [integer family](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187745%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) (and ignoring `bigint` because it's overkill):

```
Data type    Range                                                 Storage
int          -2^31 (-2,147,483,648) to 2^31-1 (2,147,483,647)      4 Bytes
smallint     -2^15 (-32,768) to 2^15-1 (32,767)                    2 Bytes
tinyint      0 to 255                                              1 Byte
```

... a `smallint` is too small, so just use `integer`.  It'll save you an extra byte every time compared to `decimal`/`numeric` every time.

Comment: thanks for the reply, but why int will always occupy 4 bytes regardless of its length. I mean if I have integer like (2,000,000) and integer like (420) will both of these integer occupy the same storage?

Comment: @johnG - They will both take up the same amount of storage, because that's how SQL Server stores them for that data type.